# The incident when Imam Ali threw away his sword when his enemy spat at his face

Tags: source-identification

> In the heat of the battle, the man spat his face and Ali forgave his
> life. Puzzled, the man asked why; and Ali said: a moment ago I was
> fighting and about to kill you in the name of Islam; now I am not so
> sure. The man asks: “Does your religion order you that?” and when he
> receives affirmative response, he becomes a Muslim.

What is the most authentic source of this incident?

Comment: I personally read this on two of the sites. Let me share those links with you. It might help you; https://www.dar-al-masnavi.org/n-I-3721.html#3.
https://onbeing.org/blog/sheath-your-sword-the-man-who-spat-on-saint-ali/